# Is there a word meaning unexpected pleasure?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A word for something you didn’t know you’d like](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27165/a-word-for-something-you-didnt-know-youd-like)

I thought *delight* might be it, but the various dictionaries I checked make no mention of the sense of surprise or unexpectedness, defining *delight* as simply heightened or extreme pleasure.

To clarify, I'm referring to the pleasure arising from some unexpected thing, not [encountering pleasure contrary to expectations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27165/a-word-for-something-you-didnt-know-youd-like).

For example: you book into a cheap hotel and have low expectations for a good experience (dirty linen, no room service, noise, etc) ... but then you discover that your favorite band is doing a gig there.

Or: you book into an expensive hotel, and figure there will be the usual roll call of luxuries perfectly executed to make your stay a pleasure ... but then you discover that your favorite band is doing a gig there.

So, a different sense from: ["Here, have a bite of this foul smelling fruit"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durian), or the unexpected outcome of combining [strawberries and balsamic vinegar](http://shine.yahoo.com/shine-food/9-weird-flavor-combinations-that-work-2608753.html), or [strawberries combined with peas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foodpairing).

Comment: I don't know of any.  The best I can come up with is a two word answer: *pleasantly surprised* but that emphasizes the surprise whereas your two words emphasize the pleasure.

Comment: _Serendipleasure_?

Comment: _Wet dream_? I had one once. After reading a Wordsworth poem in high school. Totally unexpected. Total pleasure.

Comment: @coleopterist *serendipity* includes the sense of 'happy or beneficial'

Comment: *Serendipity*. Apparently, you are looking for the word *serendipity* and its synonyms. *Serendipity* does not seem to have any one-word substitutes, though.

Comment: Main Entry: serendipity (noun) = accidental discovery. Synonyms:  _blessing, break*_, dumb luck, _fluke_, good luck, _happenstance_, happy chance, _luck_, lucky break, stumbling upon, tripping over. {* = informal/non-formal usage} Roget's 21st Century Thesaurus, 3rd Ed. Copyright © 2012, Philip Lief Group. **{NB: The 1-word substitutes are in _italics_.}**

Comment: Erics, I really think some elaboration is in order here. I can be unexpectedly pleased at the taste of my sandwich, or at a birthday party I didn't expect, or upon being notified that I've won a raffle for an automobile, or going to a play that is far better than I had hoped, or by watching my child give a speech that held 4000 people rapt until their rousing ovation. I'm not sure I'd use a single word to describe all of those. _Exuberance_ might fit, but that hardly means "unexpected pleasure" (that's more a description of the resulting feeling than of the unexpected pleasure itself).

Comment: @BillFranke: Crude as your remark may seem, I think you may be onto something. As a Boston sports fan, I watched the once-hapless Patriots become a dynasty, and the once-cursed Red Sox win not one, but two, championships. Then, the Celtics regained a taste of their glory days by beating the Lakers in the NBA Finals, and, a few years after that, the Bruins brought the Stanley Cup back to Boston after a 40-year absence. More than once, I've described that decade as "a sports fan's wet dream," because I could think of no better way to describe it. P.S. You sure do like poetry, it seems.

Comment: @J.R. A clarification then - not the sandwich, nor the play or the speech. The pleasure that arises from something that was unexpected (and pleasing).

Comment: @J.R.: It was the 2nd [Lucy poem](http://www.poetry-archive.com/w/lucy.html): "She dwelt among the untrodden ways//
Beside the springs of Dove,//A Maid whom there were none to praise//And very few to love:///A violet by a mossy stone//Half hidden from the eye!//Fair as a star, when only one//Is shining in the sky.///She lived unknown, and few could know//When Lucy ceased to be;//But she is in her grave, and oh,//The difference to me!"/// And that's what I saw in my dream. I've heard people use _wet dream_ the way you did. And once you've said it, there's nothing else to say. :-)

Comment: @Erics: So, a word like _exuberance_, _rapture_, or _euphoria_, but somehow, the element of _surprise_ or _unexpectedness_ should be embedded in the definition of the word?

Answer (score 5):

To some extent, *[breathtaking](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breathtaking#Adjective)* may serve.  This adjective has senses  “stunningly beautiful; amazing” and  “Very surprising or shocking; to such a degree as to cause astonishment”, which taken together might mean  surprising and pleasing.

Also consider the noun *[felicity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/felicity#Noun)*, with  senses “Happiness” and  “Something that is either a source of happiness or particularly apt” while the adjectival form *[felicitous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/felicitous#Adjective)* has senses “happening at the right time; appropriate, opportune, apt” and  “working out well; fortunate, opportune”, which taken all together similarly suggests  surprising and pleasing.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some single word synonyms for an *unexpected pleasure*. To help with choosing the best word for a particular use, I have also given the relevant definition. For definitions from various dictionaries of these and other senses of these words, see *OneLook.com*.

**bonanza**, *a situation leading to sudden luck, gain, or success*
**bonus**, *a gain over and above what is customary or expected*
**fortuity**, *a chance occurrence, especially a lucky one*
**godsend**, *something very helpful, especially one unearned or not to your credit*
**windfall**, *an unexpected financial gain*

Comment: As the definition shows, _bonanza_ implies some sort of tangible gain, other than mere pleasure. Still, I think it's one of the best candidates put forth so far.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't sound exactly like *unexpected pleasure*, but I thought ***thrill*** could be a close contender.

Answer (score 0):

Like some of the other suggestions, these may not be concisely equal to "unexpected pleasure", but can be used, depending on context:

***Enchanted***

***Entranced***

Answer (score 0):

The only word I can think of that comes close to what you’re looking for is *astonishment* but even then it’s not a perfect fit for your question.

From Oxford English Dictionary (OED) –

> Astonishment.
>
> 4 Mental disturbance or excitement due to the sudden presentation of anything unlooked for or unaccountable; wonder temporarily overpowering the mind; amazement.